# how to bind the data to Html Helper Class after Success of the jquery ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Hi is there anyone who can help me with the following. I am having jquery ajax get(http get) request and
having success data ,Probelem is that how to bind the data to html form or html helper class
like(@html.Dropdownlist ,@html.TextBox),
Actually I am tried to call one View as a create and edit with the help of the jquery and ajax ,i am Stuck at one point ,Please help me out ,,

My code Of jquery is

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'Get',
    url: geturl,
    data: {
        orderid: $(this).data('id')
    },
    success: function (response) {
        var CustomerID = response.cID;
        var ShipName = response.ShipName;
        $("#CustomerID").html(CustomerID);
        $("#ShipName").html(ShipName);
        return false;
    },
    error: function (e) { alert(e.error); }
});
```

how to Bind the the response data to html helper class attribute ,like i want to bind the cID to CustomerID

my View Code is

```
enter code here
  <form id="myform" >
    <div>`enter code here`
        @Html.Label("Ship Name", "ShipName");
        @Html.TextBox("ShipName", "");
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.Label("Customer", "CustomerID")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("CustomerID", String.Empty)

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `val` insted of `html`

```
$("#CustomerID").val(CustomerID);
$("#ShipName").val(ShipName);
```

Comment: Thanks Jaimin its working, Is there any way so that we can give the whole response data to Form

Comment: @Abhi if my code is help full to you then mark as ans. so it may help full to other.